# powershell command to restore remote database

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Does anyone know the powershell commands to restore a remote database from a local file?

Comment: Well, how would you do it from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, there are no PowerShell-specific commands. You'll need to use New-PSDrive to map a drive to the server, use Copy-Item to copy the database over to the server, and then use one of the SQL 2008 commands (there are 2 total) to execute the necessary RESTORE DATABASE command. SQL2008 hasn't shipped anything more specific than that, and the SQL Server product itself can't perform a restore from a remote path (well, maybe a UNC, but I assume you're on a client - it'd be easier to copy the backup to the server).